# Solving of the arguments

Tags: python, nlp

After running the code, the error is as follows:

```
usage: text-summarizer.py [-h] [-l LENGTH] filepath
text-summarizer.py: error: the following arguments are required: filepath
```

I want to solve this issue by knowing how to input the file name to this piece of code mentioned :

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("filepath", help="File name of text to summarize")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l", "--length", default=4, help="Number of sentences to return"
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

Comment: The argument parser in your program specifies that you need to supply a path on the command line when you call the program. What part has you confused?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error is not within your code, but in how you call `text-summarizer.py` in your console.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code from the console just write

```
python text-summarizer.py 'path/to/file'
```

or if you use python3:

```
python3 text-summarizer.py 'path/to/file'
```

where `path/to/file' is actually the path (on your computer) that you want to summarize

Comment: python text_summarizer.py 'C:/Users/prasu/Desktop/christ.txt'
  File "<input>", line 1
    python text_summarizer.py 'C:/Users/prasu/Desktop/christ.txt'
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: pls. do clarify on the comment mentioned above, not able to resolve this issue even with your solution.

Comment: From the information you have given us, all you should do is `python text_summarizer.py 'C:/Users/prasu/Desktop/christ.txt'`

Comment: I am using PyCharm to run this particular script, I have been typing the exact same line of code, but it still provides the same. As an alternate I copied the same piece of code on a text editor and trying executing it using cmd, same issue.

Comment: tyr without the quotes

Comment: same issue, invalid syntax

Comment: Just open `cmd`, navigate to the folder where your `text_summarizer.py` file is, and paste the line there

Comment: Issue solved, But came across a new error where im trying to input a .txt file as input, but throws IOERROR exception, so working on that.